# Spring swichUserFilter redirects to target Url without switching

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jhipster, switch-user

I have some data that i need to replicated for userA. 
As i dont know userA's password, i want to login as adminUser & switch to userA & post the data. Related to this i have two questions :-

Question 1) I am first trying to login & switch using the example given in the response here [How to impersonate user using SwitchUserFilter in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31377125/how-to-impersonate-user-using-switchuserfilter-in-spring)

```
    private final TokenProvider tokenProvider;
    protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService;//= (UserDetailsService) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    private final CorsFilter corsFilter;
    private final SecurityProblemSupport problemSupport;



    public SecurityConfiguration(UserDetailsService userDetailsService,TokenProvider tokenProvider, CorsFilter corsFilter, SecurityProblemSupport problemSupport) {
        this.tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
        this.corsFilter = corsFilter;
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.problemSupport = problemSupport;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
            .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/index.html")
            .antMatchers("/test/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilterAfter(switchUserFilter(), FilterSecurityInterceptor.class)
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(problemSupport)
            .accessDeniedHandler(problemSupport)
        .and()
            .headers()
            .frameOptions()
            .disable()
        .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/authenticate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/register").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/activate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/account/reset-password/init").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/account/reset-password/finish").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/management/health").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/info").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/prometheus").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/login/switchUser").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login/impersonate").permitAll()
        .and()
            .apply(securityConfigurerAdapter());
        // @formatter:on
    }


    @Bean
    public SwitchUserFilter switchUserFilter() {

        SwitchUserFilter filter = new SwitchUserFilter();
            filter.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
            filter.setSwitchUserUrl("/login/impersonate");
            filter.setSwitchFailureUrl("/login/switchUser");
            filter.setTargetUrl("/#/home");

        return filter;      
    }


    private JWTConfigurer securityConfigurerAdapter() {
        return new JWTConfigurer(tokenProvider);
    }
}
```

What i have tried is, i logged in as adminUser and in the url i try to switch by changing the url to http://localhost:9000/login/impersonate?username=userA

Now, my issue is i get successfully redirected to the home screen but my user remains adminUser. (i do this cause, when i make a get/post call from postman i get response saying browser is outdated & need to enable javascript)

P.S. :- I have a jhipster developed application, so most of the classes are already added by default.

P.P.S. :- I know i'm extremely dumb

Question 2) As i mentioned earlier, i need to replicate the data & i need to do it programatically, how can i achieve this ? can SwitchUserFilter  call a rest url & pass some custom data/values to it ?

Answer (score 1):

add this custom method in UserJwTController

```
@PostMapping("/authenticate-externalnodes")
    public ResponseEntity<JWTToken> authenticateExternalnodes(@Valid @RequestBody LoginVM loginVM) {
        // Get Roles for user via username
        Set<Authority> authorities = userService.getUserWithAuthoritiesByLogin(loginVM.getUsername()).get()
                .getAuthorities();
        // Create Granted Authority Rules
        Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();
        for (Authority authority : authorities) {
            grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority.getName()));
        }
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                loginVM.getUsername(), "", grantedAuthorities);
        Authentication authentication = authenticationToken;
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        boolean rememberMe = (loginVM.isRememberMe() == null) ? false : loginVM.isRememberMe();
        String jwt = tokenProvider.createToken(authentication, rememberMe);
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.add(JWTFilter.AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, "Bearer " + jwt);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new JWTToken(jwt), httpHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```