# Spring Security Adding SwitchUser Filter Has No Affect

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a simple spring security config. I am trying to add user impersonation to it. I have looked into it and I am guessing I need to use SwitchUser filter. I tried using the methods in the following blog and SO question but I am unable to get any results.

- [How to impersonate user using SwitchUserFilter in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31377125/how-to-impersonate-user-using-switchuserfilter-in-spring)
- https://blog.marcosbarbero.com/user-impersonation-with-spring-security/

Going into `/impersonate?username=k` has no affect no matter how I insert my filter. I tried inserting it using addFilter, addFilterAfter and addFilterBefore etc. So my questions are:

- Is the `/impersonate` the wrong link? Is it affected by other configurations in my project?
- When I try to print the filter chain after I update the http using `http.getObject().getFilters()` I get

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: This object has not been built
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:483) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:311) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:405) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
        at dp.server.dp.DpApplication.main(DpApplication.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: This object has not been built
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This object has not been built
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.getObject(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:55) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
        at dp.server.dp.security.SecurityConfig.configure(SecurityConfig.java:56) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:231) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:322) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:94) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
        at dp.server.dp.security.SecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1fc9c270.init(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:370) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:324) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:104) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        ... 28 common frames omitted
```

- Is my config too simple to add these custom filters such that it does not include a filter chain even? Or maybe the problem is one of the annotations I am using for the class.

I am adding important classes below. Thanks,

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    
    private final StudentService studentService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("admin").password(passwordEncoder().encode("pwd2020")).roles("ADMIN");
            
        auth.userDetailsService(studentService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/smell/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/lab/control").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/lab/results").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/lab")
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .and().addFilter(switchUserFilter());
            
    }



    @Bean
    public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SwitchUserFilter switchUserFilter() {
        SwitchUserFilter filter = new SwitchUserFilter();
        filter.setUserDetailsService(studentService);
        filter.setSwitchUserUrl("/impersonate");
        filter.setSwitchFailureUrl("/switchUser");
        filter.setTargetUrl("/lab");
        return filter;
    }
}
```

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class StudentService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException{

        final Optional<Student> optionalUser = studentRepository.findByStudentId(Long.parseLong(username));

        if (optionalUser.isPresent()) {
            return optionalUser.get();
        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(MessageFormat.format("User with email {0} cannot be found.", username));
        }
    }

    public void signUp(Student stu){
        String encPass = SecurityConfig.passwordEncoder().encode(stu.getPassword());
        stu.setPassword(encPass);
        stu = studentRepository.save(stu);
    }
}
```

EDIT: /impersonate is a POST request unlike it is mentioned like in other tutorials.

Comment: At first blush, your configuration looks fine. I'd recommend not publishing `SwitchUserFilter` as a `@Bean`, though, since Spring Boot will also register it, causing a double-registration. The other thing to consider is that impersonation is a POST by default, so in your tests, ensure that you are POSTing to the `/impersonate` endpoint.

Comment: Oh, requesting as POST worked. I was sure that I tried that hmm. Also every tutorial online either tells it as a GET request or just says go to link /impersonate. Anyways thanks a lot, this definitely solved my problem.